# How to grep the word from the begining

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to grep the file which beginning with the word "Error/"

I have tried the below grep, but it's not working. Could be a version problem? Is there another way to do this?

`grep "^Error/" Error.txt > Error1.txt`

```
Error.txt

Sample ^/Error/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX /Tab Test
Sample1 ^/Error/$ /123
Sample2  ^/mobileweb$ Error/
```

---

My OS version is `oslevel 6.1.0.0`

Please advise thanks!

Comment: I really tried to improve you wording, but I just cannot. You need to be more detailed, and precise.

Comment: The `Error` string does not appear at the start of lines. Your question should be edited to be more explicit.

Comment: Your file doesn't seem to contain any line *beginning* with `Error`.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `\b` - a word boundary - rather than `^`?

Comment: Your grep pattern is correct from what I understand you want to do. What result do you have, and what did you expect?

Comment: "oslevel" doesn't mean anything here. Which Linux distro is this? Anyway, it's not important; your Bash and Coreutils versions might make a difference, but in this case almost certainly don't.

Comment: (Some late googling appears to reveal that `oslevel` is an AIX thing, so not Linux at all.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the literal string `^/Error` (this contradicts your actual question, but seems to fit your examples), you have to escape or otherwise quote the caret character, because it has a special meaning (beginning of line) in regex.

Because many regex special characters also have a special meaning to the shell, it's best to properly quote the regex with single quotes.

```
grep '\^/Error' file
# or equivalently
grep '[^]/Error' file
# or even
grep "\\^/Error" file
```

(The last example demonstrates that the weaker quotes require backslash-escaping the backslash escape.)

Answer (score 0):

`\<`, beginning of word, `\>` end of word

admittedly, I don't really understand your question, but this answers what I think you're asking.